# Normalize State Data

Tags: php, normalization

I have a legacy form that collected state data from users. It collected the data in a text field, so the user could basically enter anything they wanted. Some sample inputs include :

```
'plattsburgh, new york'
'California'
'Central Valley,Ca/ Ptld, Oregon'
'Bay area,CA'
'new port richey florida'
'HAMPTON ROADS AREA'
'DC Metro area'
'Pennsylvania, Colorado, New York, Maryland Federal Facilities, Military Facilities,'
```

What I want to do is to programmatically normalize this data using PHP to pull out just the states and remove everything else. So given the above examples, I would like to convert them as such :

```
'plattsburgh, new york' => 'NY'
'California' => 'CA'
'Central Valley,Ca/ Ptld, Oregon' => 'OR'
'Bay area,CA' => 'CA'
'new port richey florida' => 'CA'
'HAMPTON ROADS AREA' => ''
'DC Metro area' => 'DC'
'Pennsylvania, Colorado, New York, Maryland Federal Facilities, Military Facilities,' => 'PA,CO,NY,MD'
```

Is there a nice, clean way to accomplish this?

Comment: Have you taken a look at [this](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are doing is taking user-inputted data, and trying to format it in a reliable way. As I will show in my example, this is generally a bad thing to do as user-inputted data can be full of inconsistencies. I would suggest to improve your data collection (make the user fill in a nicely laid out form, with individual fields for each part of their address, or make them select a state from a list of states). But for now, we'll look at how best to format your data, as accurately as possible.

The easiest way to achieve what it is that you are looking to do, is to generate a "map" of data, and use the map to format your data.

For example, I have created two maps, as you can see below. The first one, is a "name" to "a2" map. The array contains state names (capitalized) as indexes, and the state a2 as a value.

```
$nameToA2Map = array (
    'ALABAMA' => 'AL',
    'ALASKA' => 'AK',
    'AMERICAN SAMOA' => 'AS',
    'ARIZONA' => 'AZ',
    'ARKANSAS' => 'AR',
    'CALIFORNIA' => 'CA',
    'COLORADO' => 'CO',
    'CONNECTICUT' => 'CT',
    'DELAWARE' => 'DE',
    'DISTRICT OF COLUMBIA' => 'DC',
    'FEDERATED STATES OF MICRONESIA' => 'FM',
    'FLORIDA' => 'FL',
    'GEORGIA' => 'GA',
    'GUAM' => 'GU',
    'HAWAII' => 'HI',
    'IDAHO' => 'ID',
    'ILLINOIS' => 'IL',
    'INDIANA' => 'IN',
    'IOWA' => 'IA',
    'KANSAS' => 'KS',
    'KENTUCKY' => 'KY',
    'LOUISIANA' => 'LA',
    'MAINE' => 'ME',
    'MARSHALL ISLANDS' => 'MH',
    'MARYLAND' => 'MD',
    'MASSACHUSETTS' => 'MA',
    'MICHIGAN' => 'MI',
    'MINNESOTA' => 'MN',
    'MISSISSIPPI' => 'MS',
    'MISSOURI' => 'MO',
    'MONTANA' => 'MT',
    'NEBRASKA' => 'NE',
    'NEVADA' => 'NV',
    'NEW HAMPSHIRE' => 'NH',
    'NEW JERSEY' => 'NJ',
    'NEW MEXICO' => 'NM',
    'NEW YORK' => 'NY',
    'NORTH CAROLINA' => 'NC',
    'NORTH DAKOTA' => 'ND',
    'NORTHERN MARIANA ISLANDS' => 'MP',
    'OHIO' => 'OH',
    'OKLAHOMA' => 'OK',
    'OREGON' => 'OR',
    'PALAU' => 'PW',
    'PENNSYLVANIA' => 'PA',
    'PUERTO RICO' => 'PR',
    'RHODE ISLAND' => 'RI',
    'SOUTH CAROLINA' => 'SC',
    'SOUTH DAKOTA' => 'SD',
    'TENNESSEE' => 'TN',
    'TEXAS' => 'TX',
    'UTAH' => 'UT',
    'VERMONT' => 'VT',
    'VIRGIN ISLANDS' => 'VI',
    'VIRGINIA' => 'VA',
    'WASHINGTON' => 'WA',
    'WEST VIRGINIA' => 'WV',
    'WISCONSIN' => 'WI',
    'WYOMING' => 'WY',
);
```

As a fail-safe, we will build an array of the state a2 values too, as some fields of your data don't contain state names:

```
$a2Map = array (
    0 => 'AL',
    1 => 'AK',
    2 => 'AS',
    3 => 'AZ',
    4 => 'AR',
    5 => 'CA',
    6 => 'CO',
    7 => 'CT',
    8 => 'DE',
    9 => 'DC',
    10 => 'FM',
    11 => 'FL',
    12 => 'GA',
    13 => 'GU',
    14 => 'HI',
    15 => 'ID',
    16 => 'IL',
    17 => 'IN',
    18 => 'IA',
    19 => 'KS',
    20 => 'KY',
    21 => 'LA',
    22 => 'ME',
    23 => 'MH',
    24 => 'MD',
    25 => 'MA',
    26 => 'MI',
    27 => 'MN',
    28 => 'MS',
    29 => 'MO',
    30 => 'MT',
    31 => 'NE',
    32 => 'NV',
    33 => 'NH',
    34 => 'NJ',
    35 => 'NM',
    36 => 'NY',
    37 => 'NC',
    38 => 'ND',
    39 => 'MP',
    40 => 'OH',
    41 => 'OK',
    42 => 'OR',
    43 => 'PW',
    44 => 'PA',
    45 => 'PR',
    46 => 'RI',
    47 => 'SC',
    48 => 'SD',
    49 => 'TN',
    50 => 'TX',
    51 => 'UT',
    52 => 'VT',
    53 => 'VI',
    54 => 'VA',
    55 => 'WA',
    56 => 'WV',
    57 => 'WI',
    58 => 'WY',
);
```

We can then use these arrays to format your data:

```
//we'll format the states into this array
$statesFormatted = array();

//if your states data is a string like displayed in your post:
$states = "
'plattsburgh, new york'
'California'
'Central Valley,Ca/ Ptld, Oregon'
'Bay area,CA'
'new port richey florida'
'HAMPTON ROADS AREA'
'DC Metro area'
'Pennsylvania, Colorado, New York, Maryland Federal Facilities, Military Facilities,'
";
//read the string into an array, by splitting up the new lines:
$stateFields = explode("\n",$states);

//if your states data is an array:
$stateFields = array(
    'plattsburgh, new york',
    'California',
    'Central Valley,Ca/ Ptld, Oregon',
    'Bay area,CA',
    'new port richey florida',
    'HAMPTON ROADS AREA',
    'DC Metro area',
    'Pennsylvania, Colorado, New York, Maryland Federal Facilities, Military Facilities,',
);


//go through each state field
foreach($stateFields as $field) {
    //remove the single quotes?
    //$field = str_replace("'","",$field);

    //first, we look to try and match a name to a2
    foreach($nameToA2Map as $name => $a2) {
        //if the name can be found in the field
        if(strpos(strtoupper($field),$name) !== false) {
            //match!!
            $statesFormatted[$field] = $a2;
            //we break here, as we don't need to search anymore
            break;
        }
    }

    //lets check that we found a match
    if(!isset($statesFormatted[$field])) {
        //we didn't find a match, lets smartly try and find an a2 value in the field
        foreach($a2Map as $a2) {
            if(preg_match("/[\W]".$a2."[\W]/", $field) >= 1) {
                //match!!
                $statesFormatted[$field] = $a2;
                //we break here, as we don't need to search anymore
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    //if we still can't find a match, then we we do some sort of fail-safe here...
    if(!isset($statesFormatted[$field])) {
        $statesFormatted[$field] = "COULD NOT MATCH!";
    }
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($statesFormatted);
echo "</pre>";
```

The above will output:

`Array
(
    [plattsburgh, new york] => NY
    [California] => CA
    [Central Valley,Ca/ Ptld, Oregon] => OR
    [Bay area,CA] => COULD NOT MATCH!
    [new port richey florida] => FL
    [HAMPTON ROADS AREA] => COULD NOT MATCH!
    [DC Metro area] => COULD NOT MATCH!
    [Pennsylvania, Colorado, New York, Maryland Federal Facilities, Military Facilities,] => CO
)`

If you note, within the final lines of the code, I make a final check to see if a field could not be matched, and give it a value of "COULD NOT MATCH!". These are fields where the user-inputted data is too inconsistent to easily match. You could either disregard these fields as inconsistent data, or add additional conditions to the `$nameToA2Map` array. I wouldn't recommend doing this though.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Very helpful. This is a legacy form, so I am cleaning up old code written by someone else to try to make it more consistent. The new form will use pre-formatted input fields, but I can't just remove the records with the bad data, I have to normalize it to include it in the new database. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I would highly recommend keeping your old `bad data` seperate. Ultimately, trying to make the old inconsistent data consistent might actually be far more work than it is worth, and will often result in the inheritance of problems. If you have no choice in the matter though, make sure to set expectations (there will be inconsistencies...)

Comment: I don't have a choice but to keep the old data and attempt to normalize it. I understand this won't be perfect, but it is necessary.